# How to create a Menu from Taxonomy Terms in Orchard 1.7+ CMS using query / projection?

Tags: navigation, orchardcms, taxonomy, projection, orchard-modules

in Orchard CMS before the Taxonomy Widget was deprecated, you use to be able to create a menu of your Taxonomy terms very easily, like so:

Section

Big House (12)

- Bathroom (1)
- Room1 (6)
- Room2 (2)
- Room3 (3)

[Small House (1)](http://google.com)

- Room1 (0)
- [Room2 (1)](http://google.com)
- Toilet (0)

Each link would display a listing of all the Content Items with the appropriate term.
After the abolishment, you’re supposed to use queries > projection to handle such, though in true Orchard Style, there is zero documentation for the layman web creator [not coder/developer, which I’m fast realising Orchard is only suitable for] to be able to access and hopefully replicate.
In all seriousness - I have tried everything, so can anyone tell me the steps to create this simple menu if it is indeed possible?
Here is an example Taxonomy:

```
Section
    Big House
       Bathroom
       Room1
       Room2
       Room3
    Small House
       Room1
       Room2
       Toilet
```

All my attempts filtering the section term display every field of the content item, and when I use shape tracing to create an alternate to remove all the redundant data, the template is blank [obviously it’s created in code or something]. 
Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...hmm, I know exactly what you mean - Orchard's documentation is, and always has been, *shameful*!  I needed something similar, recently, so inquired through the Forums and got no reply? So after much trial and error [code word for wasting many days on what used to be so simple] I managed to:

```
*Add a query: "Section" or the likes [your questions denotes Section]
*Add a Filter <has terms> - you should see your Taxonomy in the Terms List Box, select the parent, and "Is one of".
*Add a Second Filter <Title Part, Title> operator -- is equal to; Value -- Section{Content.Fields.Product.Section}
*Save and preview ;)
```

Then you just have to add a widget...

Let me know how you go, but perhaps you look to another end-user friendly CMS before you get too invested - Orchard has so much potential, but is severely lacking in docs/tuts/examples etc. that you may continue to struggle. Good luck with it.